# How to convert variable frequency small AC signal to square wave

Tags: esp32

I have been given an RM Young wind monitor (Nice!) but there is no amplifier circuit with it (Yikes!) here's the model: http://www.youngusa.com/Manuals/05103-90(M).pdf

My problem is with the wind speed, I'm trying to measure this with an ESP-wroom-32 and can't get my head around a good all around simple circuit to convert the wind speed signal into pulses of varying frequencies. In a nutshell, the wind speed monitor is a fixed coil and three magnets are attached to the rotor so we get a 80mv peak to peak up to 8 volts peak to peak signal of varying frequency proportional to 3 times the RPM (up to 10000 rpm). I tried a schmitt trigger but I get either a lot of false positive pulses or nothing at all. Here's my circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fV9EJt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Am I at least on good tracks? After searching for a while I found the schematic of the OEM amplifier circuit: https://s.campbellsci.com/documents/ca/manuals/05603c_man.pdf
I have a very old oscilloscope with a 3 inch viewport, I believe I noticed disturbances in the sine wave, I believe that could be caused by the diode?

Comment: no takers?......

Comment: It looks like the impedance is around \$100\:\text{k}\Omega\$ for that circuit you referenced. I don't know, myself, if that's the best load for your wind speed sensor's inductance. But I have to assume that the designers of R. M. Young Company intended that value for the wind speed sensor. So I am not going to disagree with it without better information. Given that, I'd say you are loading it down too much with your schematic. How did you measure the range of voltages?

Comment: Simon, I'm thinking maybe three BJTs?

Comment: Simon, If you don't indicate that you exist then I'm not sure there will be much more to see. (Perhaps what's here is already enough, though.)

Comment: hey @jonk I assure you I do exist... or do I?

Comment: Anyway by the referenced circuit you meant one in the manual? The voltage range comes from the RMyoung wind monitor manual available on their website: http://www.youngusa.com/Manuals/05106-90(N).pdf

Comment: @Simon Okay. So that makes sense. And I now know that you didn't actually take any measurements, yet. You may want to do so. It would perhaps be one of the first things I did -- experimenting with the sensor a bit to "get a feel" for how it behaves. But the numbers on paper do seem to say that the resistive part of the source impedance is \$2\:\text{k}\Omega\$. I want to assume those voltages were measured using \$1\:\text{M}\Omega\$, or more, for the load. But I'm just a hobbyist, and haven't been given my crystal ball for spec-reading like others get, so you should run some tests to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my [$500 design](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgTCAMB0lwbOaBmA7GAHGArBgjAJxhiTZ7aLaQjY3XYCmAtHngFADuIyGALCHlSJeYfoMSROIXugGZps8VDYBjbnwFD1-EhihRYcOAROmz5giCYwjeXsgKQ8kUyUfxZNp2wBONbBB48jKB8tTORka%202pqIyPJK4ZFS2AECaamhepJcmQJE-oFpkgCGCoEFeYQQerRJkdRg0FRgyNhovGTwqdiWTS28BKgtVATI8IgRUX4hsdKic-VwbGXVc2CKWnrOVngCDXBIVEbxkPAYw2v9%208mC1Irw1Lzhj-p40B4CnzbI3FIbgS0AIE42UXGBeFBELC0Tw5y%20STEryWkj80O28KC2RuDVU%20yR90CyJAGGghAsFOYfWggzGeAw8CIyB4QW6Bjg7C4cO2CUxyKk3IR%20SJ1FRMV03HkEpR0VmEpEOkg2KmOWF4CVkr00qkPEVegV6uyAoKayuGskACV5nrreBPPpnkd9KLmmwAEbcZDhIK7HQUMGexA4OJA-2SADm3FDIaD8H4orYz1%20omo8W48IIEgEeAA%20nGc5Ac0FsLx4DnsGSwOcmQReLxWAEwAXDE4Czmm6wc8g2AAPKwTcD2O06UvSOQgACCADsGABbAD2s4YABcGD4ADoAZwAygBLWfQLfvVBb5fzo8eLcACQAXlvHlvZwA1AAOL9P5838CfW4AFCUABsF03ZcAEpojyUR9VkKC3gOVU5Q1OVeCNXI0jWSCUOUJMaFBNMJn4TN9DLfNC2LUtyxbDk%20CwCY7F4ZtbDbJsy27AC7UBOIfUSdknF4pwq1EDYeFQTMAjGVBlD8ZBuK0eJti0VMvUkecQEmN4cFHCsGnpFCq3gej%20L2Ro1L%20IA) using $1 in parts on a perf board.  All balanced with STP cable and decoupled with Vdd cap not shown. Single supply [CMOS OA](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20001669e.pdf)  high Gain > 110 dB Rail to Rail. GBW=15kHz

The simulator differentiates a sweep signal of 60 mVpp from 1.7 to 166.7 Hz to output ~ 6Vpp max. (Lower for margin)

Then the desired response is a LPF with 50 dB gain to square up the 60 mV signal with balanced positive feedback ratio to suppress noise. I assume you use good EMI practice and use STP cable.

It requires a Vdd/2 DC bias on the signal source for single supply use.
I used 2.5 assuming 5V , but you can use 3.3V/2 all the way down to 1.6V/2.. It's not critical for the value, but it must be low impedance buffered.

Feel free to ask questions. It's a balanced negative and positive feedback amplifier with a 10M/10k Ratio to a common C differential LPF to the breakpoint.

[image]

If you have noise issues , two 1% caps to gnd (matched) 1 on each side of input after 10k.

Comment: Nice! how did you figure the anemometer sim circuit? I will surely keep this around as this might get handy. However I fear that 167hz is far too low. a 20 km/h wind would mean around 3.4 KHz. I tried changing the upper sweep limit on the Sine generator but for a reason I don't get, it get stuck at 208hz

Comment: BTW did you knew the actual module that does this job really cost 500$?

Comment: Did I mistake the output ? Sorry. But that’s easy to scale up by reducing both C values
x3 per rev? X 100m/s / (0.098 m/s per Hz)  = ?
 Transducer Output

Comment: $500 ? No that was my tongue in cheek what I used to charge per day for design over 30 yrs ago.  Now factor inflation and pay it forward.

Comment: Take a look here: http://www.youngusa.com/products/7/8.html at the bottom you have the sensor interface at 490USD pretty dead on! I believe we are both wrong for the output hehe I brought up that number too fast. 10000 rpm/60 = 167 indeed but 3 times that since we have 3 cycles per rpm so max freq at 501Hz. I'll try fiddling around with your circuit and tune it to get up to 500 Hz.

Comment: Reduce both C's/3 & scale FM min max x3